# Table layout and float left and bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tablelayout

I have researched for this question, but did't get the satisfying answer. I am using bootstrap's grid layout.

Please look at the [**`Fiddle here`**](https://jsfiddle.net/7zLcgzqm/) and resize the output window - while resizing you may have noticed that when widow size large enough to add *col-sm-* classes, my table layout breaks.

What I want is height of both column should be same when they are next to each other (height of largest element), and when they are top/bottom to each other, they should take their own height (which is working now).

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="architect-table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell column-1 col-xs-12 col-sm-6"> abcde </div>
        <div class="cell column-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-6"> abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.architect-table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
 }

.row {
     display: table-row;
}

.cell {
     display: table-cell;
     min-height: 44px;
     border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

However I know, if I remove `float: left` style, everything will work fine. But I can't as I want a bootstrap's grid layout. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `flexbox` is an option, you can make your `row` a *wrapping* `flexbox` - see demo below:

```css
.architect-table {
  width: 100%;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.architect-table > .row > .cell {
  min-height: 44px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="architect-table">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell column-1 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">abcde</div>
      <div class="cell column-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde
        abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Best posible solution using `flex` on my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sad to say but currently Bootstrap don't have this functionality, in case you want to have the same height on two `cols` when they are next each other you need to play with JS, there are some libraries that can help you, normally I use [jQuery.matchHeight](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height) because is easy to use.

Best solution is don't use Bootstrap grid when you want this behavior and use `flex` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex. Please check this [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/muhsin84/7zLcgzqm/1/)

```
.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row > [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to override all `.row > [class*='col-']` with `flex`. :)

Comment: correct. It is just for his reference mean he may use some class. But what you said is right. Thanks.